# Angular ForEach loop with Firebase call async issue

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code:

```
getTotalBookListCost(bookList:string[]):number
  {
    let cost=0;
    bookList.forEach(el=>{
      this.store.doc("Books/"+el).get().subscribe(data=>{
        let temp=<Book>data.data();
        cost+=temp.cost;
      },error=>this.toastr.error(error.message));
    });
    return cost;
  }
```

The value returned is 0, i guess because the return is executed before the forEach loop with firebase calls. How to return only after the loop is executed?

Comment: your store.doc is async function you can not use as like this change toPromise or Observable return.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the function returns the data first, before the firebase returns the data. What you could try to do is to use combineLatest operator, something like this:

```
getTotalBookListCost(bookList:string[]):Observable<number>
{
  let cost=0;
  return 
  combineLatest(bookList.map(el=>this.store.doc("Books/"+el).get())
  .pipe(
      map(result=> {
        const bookCosts = result.map(data => data.data().cost);
        return bookCosts.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
      })
  );
}
```

You need to be aware that now your function will return an Obserbable, not a number.

Edit: as Andrei rightly said, the function returned Subscription, not Observable. I've fixed it now, so you need to be aware that you need to subscribe to it.

Comment: here Subscription is returned, which is not right